# Designing a loop that fetches 5 random vectors each with 5 components from a set of 10 until Linear dependence is found

Tags: matrix, vector, infinite-loop, random

I am currently trying to find a way to make a loop that will select 5 random columns without replacement of a 5x10 matrix until it finds a determinant equal to 0 out of the new matrix formed by the 5 random selections. The 5x10 matrix comes from multiplying the matrix representation of the dihedral group, $D_{10}$ by random (for now) vectors in $R^5$. I then need the loop to create a new vector from $R^5$ and repeat until a vector is found such that the determinant $\neq$ 0. I have written the code that can perform all of these calculations individually, but am trully struggling with the automation of this process via a loop since I am really new to Mathematica. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm not exactly sure how to format the code I have up for a post but here is what I've done so far...

```
\[CapitalGamma] = {{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 
     0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 
     0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 
     0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
     0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
     0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 
     0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 
     0, 1, 0, 0}}};   
v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  
\[CapitalRho] = Permutations[v];  
ovld = \[CapitalGamma].v;  
Tovld = Transpose[\[CapitalGamma].v];
l = RandomSample[ovld, 5];  
lt = Transpose[l];
lrr = RowReduce[l];
d = Det[l]
```

Comment: Show what you've gotten so far, that is what's your code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: So I defined $\Gamma$ to be the $D_{10}$ matrix representation, $\mathbf P$ to be the set of permutations of 5 elements of $R^5$ without replacement, and $v$ to be the first item in $\mathbf P$.

I then set i = RandomSample[$\Gamma*v$, 5] and am using RowReduce[i] to visually check for dependence. I need each iteration to subtract $\Gamma*v$ from $\mathbf P$ so that once the loop starts again, I'm getting a unique 5x10 matrix from which to work on. I'll do away with RowReduce[i] and set the loop to stop when Determinant[i]=0.

Comment: I feel like since the procedure involves set and matrix operations, this loop isn't as simple as I'd like it to be for a beginner.

Comment: Terrence, it would be most useful if you could add the code, rather than a description thereof, to your original question. You can edit your question at any time (use the "edit" link under the question itself).

Comment: Sorry, OP updated with code

Comment: I have formatted your code (just a matter of indenting with 4 spaces) and also gotten rid of the `MatrixForm` wrappers. These frequently cause problems/confusion (the documentation is not correct to say that it affects display but not evaluation; it certainly affects evaluation as well), so we can do without them, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. You're right, ultimately the result are the same, just as lists of rows.

Answer (score 1):

This should give some ideas. I add a safety valve in case the rank is always 5.

```
indx = 0;
det = 1;
While[det != 0 && indx < 100,
 indx++;
 l = RandomSample[ovld, 5];
 det = Det[l];]
{indx, l}

(* Out[163]= {3, {{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 5},
{2, 1, 5, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}}} *)
```

Comment: This is fantastic, than you. I guess I had enough there. Thanks you.

Comment: Is there any way to be sure that "RandomeSample" doesn't repeat the the same collection of 5 vectors here?

Comment: Not easily in general, but for this case not so hard. You could take the set of all `Binomial[10,5]` subsets and suffle them e.g. with `RandomChoice`. Then just iterate over the result until you find one you like.